# Getting a Powershell session(shell) on aks containers

Tags: azure, powershell, kubectl, azure-aks

I want to have an interactive powershell session on AKS windows containers. I see there is a cmd for Linux bash session which is "kubectl exec --stdin --tty shell-demo -- /bin/bash" Is there anything similar for creating a powershell session for windows containers?

Answer (score 0):

You can both SSH and RDP into Windows nodes on AKS, but it can be a bit tricky.

You need to first SSH into another node on the cluster, then SSH into the Windows node.

[Here is a doc that outlines the process.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh#create-the-ssh-connection-to-a-windows-node)

You might also want to consider using RDP.